# Post Difficulty due to different parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller I am having the following code

```
public ActionResult Tests(int clientID, string clientName)
    {
        TestModel model = new TestModel (clientID, clientName);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Tests(TestModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            model.Save(model);
            return GetClientView();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", e.Message);
            return RedirectToAction("Tests");
        }
    }
```

In my MyPage.cshtml I have

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<h2> @Model.ClientName</h2>

...
<p> <input type ="submit"  value="Save" id="submit" />
     </p>
}
```

However, upon clicking on the submit button, I am having the error message

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.MissingMethodException: No
>   parameterless constructor defined for
>   this object.

The page source shows the following

```
<form action="/Client/Tests?clientID=891&amp;clientName=Another%20Client" method="post">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a parameterless constructor in your `TestModel` :

```
public class TestModel
{
    public TestModel()
    {
    }
}
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Tests", "YourController")
    {
        <div id="create-event">
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientId)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientId)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientName)
            </div>                             

            <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: I am still having the same error, it doesn`t even reach the action for the post

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to insert or update your model before the save.

With Entity Framework

Update:

```
Try
{
         TryUpdateModel(model);
         model.Save(model);
         return GetClientView();
}
```

Insert:

```
Try
{
        AddToTable(model); // Table being your Entity Model's entity type name
        model.Save(model);
        return GetClientView();
}
```